# Chrome tapping on touchpad fires mouseleave

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, mouseleave, touchpad

Recently, my website began to work quite weirdly in Chrome. I found that in Chrome, tapping a touchpad now (since a recent update?) fires two events - `click` and `mouseleave`.

```
<div id="tap">HOVER, TAP or CLICK</div>
<script>
tap.addEventListener("mouseleave",function(){alert("mouseleave");});
tap.addEventListener("click",function(){alert("click");});
</script>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3xx164f/):

So far, it seems like this issue only applies to Google Chrome. In Firefox and Yandex (Chromium based) fake `mouseleave` doesn't fire. Clicking by button (either mouse or touchpad button) also works fine - no `mouseleave`.

How can i prevent this mouseleave on tap? Or, maybe, there's a way to tell a tap-mouseleave from the real mouseleave?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem on my laptop, any specific version of chrome?

Comment: Umm... no. Version 41.0.2272.118 (Latest stable to the date, afaik). You mean, if you tap the yellow div by a touchpad, you don't receive "mouseleave" event?

Comment: Correct, tapping with touchpad only triggers "click" for me. Running version 41.0.2272.118 m.

Comment: Oh... kay.... Must be something with extensions in my chrome? I recently added a Pinterest button... But now wiped out everything, and the problem is still there...

Comment: Now switched Chrome into "Windows 8 Mode" - and the problem is gone. I have no rational idea about this :(

Comment: I reported this bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=863373

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've noticed that when the incorrect tapping behavior happens in Chrome, we can inspect the `mouseleave` event object to determine if it's the buggy behavior or not:

```
mouseleave = function (e) {
  if (e.screenX === 0 && e.screenY === 0) {
    // BUG in Chrome
    return;
  }
  // Correct behavior...
}
```

Alternatively, we can check `e.toElement` and/or `e.relatedTarget`, since I've noticed those being `null` when the buggy behavior happens:

```
mouseleave = function (e) {
  if (!e.relatedTarget || !e.toElement) {
    // BUG in Chrome
    return;
  }
  // Correct behavior...
}
```

Comment: This response was a lifesaver. Wish this answer were accepted!